# space in url; did browser got smarter or server?

Tags: browser, webserver

It looks like today you no longer to have to encode spaces by %20 in your html links or image links. For example, suppose you have this image at 〔http://example.com/i/my house.jpg〕. Notice the space there. In your html code, you can just do this:

```
<img src="http://example.com/i/my house.jpg" alt="my house">
```

It work in all current version of browsers. Though, what i'm not sure is that whether the browser encodes it before requesting the url, or a particular server will do the right with with paths with space? (apache)

Addendum:
sorry about the confusion. My real question is about HTTP protocol.
I'll leave this one as is and mark Answered.
I posted a new question here.
[does HTTP protocol require space be encoded in file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673809/does-http-protocol-require-space-be-encoded-in-file-path)

Comment: PS i know that percent encoding is required in URL. Anyway, am wondering now if http protocol requires encoding for the space char when used in file path for the GET header line. (tried to test with telnet... but i forgot what other header are necessary so i aborted the test)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The browser makes the correction.

You still have to encode the spaces though.  Just because it works in the browsers you use doesn't make it valid, and doesn't mean it will work everywhere.

You can see a list of reserved characters and other characters that should be encoded here:  http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

[RFC1738](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) specifically states:

> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
>      reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
>      unencoded within a URL.

[RFC2396](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) takes place over RFC1738 and expounds on space usage in URLs:

> The space character is excluded because significant spaces may
>      disappear and insignificant spaces may be introduced when URI are
>      transcribed or typeset or subjected to the treatment of word-
>      processing programs.  Whitespace is also used to delimit URI in many
>      contexts.

Comment: does http protocol requires encoding of space in file names? e.g. in "GET /some thing.html HTTP/1.1"

Comment: @Xah Lee: HTTP doesn't know anything about file names, it only knows about URLs. `/some thing.html` may be (part of) a file name on the server but that's an implementation detail, HTTP just sees a URL that has a space in it. The %20 (encoded space character) might have been decoded before the web server logged that though.

Comment: @Xah Lee, I think the RFC is pretty clear.  RFC2616 specifically references RFC2396 for URI formatting.  RFC2396 takes place of RFC1738, which I have reference in my answer.  Part 2.4.3 of RFC2396 (http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) says that "The space character is excluded because significant spaces may disappear and insignificant spaces may be introduced when URI are transcribed or typeset or subjected to the treatment of word-processing programs. Whitespace is also used to delimit URI in many contexts."  So, yes the encoding of space is required.

Comment: @Brad. Thanks for the well informed answer. I posted a new question here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673809/does-http-protocol-require-space-be-encoded-in-file-path

Comment: @Xah Lee, how did I not already answer your question?  How many ways can I answer **YES** it is required.

Comment: hi Brad, your are right. The issue was a bit confusing to me because it involves encoding in several levels. What i was not clear when reading your answer was that you kept mentioning uri but i know already uri requires it. In HTTP protocol, it WAS not clear to me what's needed there, because it is not exactly a URI in its full form. RFCs referenced kept mentioning URI but are not HTTP protocol references... added the fact that specs are sometimes totally ignored in practice. Anyway, it's cleared. Thanks a lot for your answers and references.