# Decode URL parameters having special characters

Tags: php, json

I have a URL like this, i want to get value of variable "json" but i am not getting values after & parameters from "Hindi : L&W 3rd poem 3 times. Soc Science : L&W hard words 5 times.". How to get value of json correctly??

Note: I am getting value of json from app side so i cannot encode string before converting it into json string.

```
http://localhost/abc/sendMsg.php?json={"studentId":"15","msg":"Hindi : L&W 3rd poem 3 times. Soc Science : L&W hard words 5 times."}
```

Comment: `base64_encode` string then send to `sendMsg.php` there you can decode it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, the app in the client's browser generates the JSON array. In that case, you should try using JSON.stringify

```
<script>
    url = "http://localhost/abc/sendMsg.php?json="+JSON.stringify(yourJSON);
</script>
```

**EDIT**

Alright, so from your comment you told be you're receiving the URL in PHP.

> NOTE: The best practice would be to escape the URL from Android. If it is not escaped before sending, it will cause problems with some browsers/apps that might not support special characters. See this thread for the specific RFC: [space in url; did browser got smarter or server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665124/space-in-url-did-browser-got-smarter-or-server)

If not possible *as a fallback*, I would advise splitting the URL to only retrieve the string, instead of using the `$_GET` parameter.

You could try something like:

```
<?php 

$urlParts = explode('?json=', 'http://localhost/abc/sendMsg.php?json={"studentId":"15","msg":"Hindi : L&W 3rd poem 3 times. Soc Science : L&W hard words 5 times."}');
$jsonPart = end($urlParts);

$decodedJson = json_decode($jsonPart);

?>
```

Comment: for that also i need "yourJSON" value how to get that?

Comment: First of all, my example relies on the fact that this code is executed client's side, using Javascript. From what I see in other comments, it could also look like you would want to create the URL from the server's side, using PHP. Which one is the scenario you need help with? We can then go forward with more explanation.

Comment: No I dont want to create URL from server side, I am having this URL from which I am not able to get json variable value properly because of '&' character

Comment: So you are receiving this URL in a Javascript function? I just want to make sure what language we're talking about.

Comment: Thank you @Marc-Antoine I was doing this only

Answer (score 0):

please use below code

```
$str='[{"studentId":"15","msg":"Hindi : L&W 3rd poem 3 times. Soc Science : L&W hard words 5 times."}]';
print_r(json_decode($str));
```

output

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [studentId] => 15 [msg] => Hindi : L&W 3rd poem 3 times. Soc Science : L&W hard words 5 times. ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

convert it to an array after getting It  by Using $_Request[]

then Use for each loop to get specific value

```
foreach ($json_array as $key => $value){
$hindi = $value->Hindi;
 echo $hindi;
```

`}`